# Memory error while resizing CINIC-10 dataset

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, conv-neural-network

I am working on CINIC-10 dataset for by using transfer learning. Dataset is (32,32), but for VGG-16 and Resnet-50 models I need to resize is to (224,224). Challenging part is I am getting memory error whatever I tried. Here is my recent code below:

```
x_train_224 = []

for i in range(100,90100,100):
  for j in range(i-100,i):
    x_train_224.append(cv2.resize(x_train[i], (224, 224)))
```

[And here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NrIm.png)

I tried to to split it to the groups which have 100 images but still it's not working. How should I deal with that problem?

Comment: You should also post the error message

Comment: I've noticed you don't use your innermost counter ' j ' in your logic, why is that? Maybe something is missing

Comment: Does this help x_train_224.append(cv2.resize(x_train_224[i], (224, 224)))?